# É possivel criar um input uppercase e manter o placeholder em lowercase apenas em CSS?

Tags: css

Como posso deixar o meu placeholder em lowercase e meu texto em uppercase em css?

Já tentei:

```css
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="usuário">
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Como é uma propriedade do CSS3 cada browser implementou de uma forma esse seletor, aí você tem que usar os vendor prefix.

```css
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome, Safari */
  text-transform: lowercase;
}


:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-transform: lowercase; 
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-transform: lowercase;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  /* IE */
   text-transform: lowercase; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="usuário">
```

Comment: Comentar cada um dos seletores foi muito bom para a respsota +1 :)

Answer (score 13):

Tente assim

```css
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   text-transform: lowercase; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="usuário">
```

Comment: Troque `-webkit-input-placeholder` por  `::-webkit-input-placeholder` para que funcione no Chrome também. +1

Comment: @abfurlan É uma bagunça esse seletor, os browsers não concordam quanto ao nome, nem quanto à classificação como pseudo-classe ou pseudo-elemento. E agora decidiram voltar a tratar como pseudo-classe e [mudar o nome](http://css4.rocks/selectors-level-4/placeholder-pseudo-class.php) para `:placeholder-shown` (que ninguém suporta ainda).