# Style Placeholder Text em determinada div ou input

Tags: css

Como posso determina o lugar onde o estilo vai ficar usando a função?

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

Exemplo tenho 4 input com diferentes formatação de placeholder.

Comment: Solucionado = > http://www.devmedia.com.br/html5-placeholder-como-estilizar/24589

Comment: Se vc quiser pode postar uma resposta com a solução.

Comment: Essa aqui tb é solução pra essa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104745/